# PHPickerViewController Disregards Order Photo is Selected

Tags: ios, swift, phpickerviewcontroller

I use a `PHPickerViewController` to select profile images and want the first photo selected to be a user's hero image.

Whenever I return the selected results, the order in which I selected is not reflected.

I've double checked my config and looked at existing SO answers, but no solution has worked and would appreciate any guidance that does not involve using a 3rd party!

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/selecting_photos_and_videos_in_ios) states by simply setting the `.selection` property to `.ordered`, a user's selected order should be respected, but it does not...

```
//Setup code

var config = PHPickerConfiguration()    
config.selectionLimit = 3
    config.filter = .images
    config.selection = .ordered
    
    let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
    picker.delegate = self

//Delegate handler

func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
                
guard !results.isEmpty else {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    return
}

self.photos = []

var tempImages: [Int: UIImage] = [:]
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for (index, result) in results.enumerated() {
     
     dispatchGroup.enter() // Enter the group

     result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { [weak self] object, error in
         defer { dispatchGroup.leave() }

         guard let self = self else { return }

         if let image = object as? UIImage {
             
             tempImages[index] = image
         }
     }
 }

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
                            
    guard let self = self else { return }
    
    for index in 0..<tempImages.keys.count {
        
        if let image = tempImages[index] {
                                
            self.photos?.append(image)
        }
    }
}
        
picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: If you can prove that `.ordered` does not in fact send you the results in the same order as the numbers, file a bug. My answer will allow you to prove it (or disprove it). If `.ordered` _does_ send you the results in order, the resulting array of images will be in the right order. If it doesn't, no magic can fix that, as you do evidently would then not know the order.

Comment: I have Objective-C version of your code and when I set the `source` to "ordered", it works as expected - the array of images matches the user's selection order. The only difference in my code from yours is that I build an array of image URLs from the results instead of an array of `UIImage`. If I do not set the `source` to "ordered" then the array of images is not in the same order that the user selected them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't answer the question of the order in which the `results` array arrives, but you can greatly simplify your code and be certain of getting your images in the same order as the `results` array by introducing this extension to NSItemProvider:

```
extension NSItemProvider {
    @objc func loadImage() async throws -> UIImage {
        enum ImageLoadingError: Error {
            case couldNotConvertDataToImage
            case unknown
        }
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) { data, error in
                if let data {
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                        continuation.resume(returning: image)
                    } else {
                        continuation.resume(throwing: ImageLoadingError.couldNotConvertDataToImage)
                    }
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error ?? ImageLoadingError.unknown)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to simply loop in a very ordinary way thru the `results`, in order, without all the hair-raising complication of the dispatch group:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
for result in results {
    let provider = result.itemProvider
    do {
        let image = try await provider.loadImage()
        images.append(image)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

(You'll have to get into an async context to make that call, obviously; but that's easy.) The output `images` is guaranteed to match the order of the `results` and the code is far simpler and can be reasoned about.